# MySQL: UPDATE ... ON DUPLICATE KEY "ANOTHER UPDATE"?

Tags: mysql, duplicates, sql-update

I've stumbled on a problem which is supposedly should have a valid solution in a single MySQL query, yet I can't figure it out (I'm far from an expert in MySQL, alas).

The table has the following columns: A, B, C. (A, B) is a primary key (INTs). C - is a string. The table is populated with records.

Under some conditions I need to update a value `x` in column A to new value `y`. If some records do already have `y` in A (can be many at once, for records with different values in B), "duplicate key(s)" condition occurs. In such case, I need to concatenate values in C from old records and corresponding pending updates, for every specific `b`.

Example:

```
|  A  |  B  |   C
|  1  |  2  |  ABC
|  1  |  4  |  DEF
|  2  |  2  |  GHI
|  2  |  4  |  JKL
|  2  |  5  |  MNO
```

After update in A as 2 -> 1, I need to get:

```
|  A  |  B  |   C
|  1  |  2  |  ABCGHI
|  1  |  4  |  DEFJKL
|  1  |  5  |  MNO
```

There is a well-known `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement. But how to handle gracefully the same problem on updates? I'm not sure if and how `REPLACE` statement or `REPLACE` function can be used for the task.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, whatever happens, you will need two statements:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD UNIQUE INDEX (A, B);

INSERT INTO myTable (A, B, C)
  SELECT 1, B, C
  FROM   myTable t
  WHERE  A = 2
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  C = CONCAT(myTable.C, VALUES(C))
;

DELETE FROM myTable WHERE A = 2;
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e17b/1/0).

If there is a risk of concurrency issues, you will obviously need to perform these within a transaction to preserve atomicity.

Comment: Thank you. I'll accept your answer in 2 minutes ;-) [SO limitation].